# ValueError: TensorFlow2 Input 0 is incompatible with layer model

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am trying to code a ResNet CNN architecture based on the [paper](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2017/pdfs/12.pdf) by using Python3, TensorFlow2 and CIFAR-10 dataset. You can access the Jupyter notebook [here](https://github.com/arjun-majumdar/CNN_Classifications/blob/master/ResNet_9_CIFAR10.ipynb).

During training the model using "model.fit()", after just one epoch of training, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected
> shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), found shape=(32, 32, 3)

The training images are batched using batch_size = 128, hence the training loop gives the following 4-d tensor which TF Conv2D expects- (128, 32, 32, 3).

What's the source of this error?

Comment: Please include the code here and not on another site

Comment: I ran your code on colab. I took the code from your notebook. It's running fine here. Have you test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a small issue in your code. The problem occurs in the test data set. You forget to transform it properly. So currently you have like this

```
images, labels = next(iter(test_dataset))
images.shape, labels.shape

(TensorShape([32, 32, 3]), TensorShape([10]))
```

You need to do the same transformation on the test as you did on the train set. But of course, things you consider: no shuffling, no augmentation.

```
def testaugmentation(x, y):
    x = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(x, HEIGHT + 8, WIDTH + 8)
    x = tf.image.random_crop(x, [HEIGHT, WIDTH, NUM_CHANNELS])
    return x, y

def normalize(x, y):
    x = tf.image.per_image_standardization(x)
    return x, y

test_dataset = (test_dataset
        .map(testaugmentation)
        .map(normalize)
        .batch(batch_size = batch_size, drop_remainder = True))

images, labels = next(iter(test_dataset))
images.shape, labels.shape
(TensorShape([128, 32, 32, 3]), TensorShape([128, 10]))
```